# Get file name from TUI class to different class

Tags: java

Currently working on a tui application to prompt the user to enter a file name and then I need to get that name from the TUI class over to a model class. Every thing I try gives me the error "Cannot make a static reference to the non-static method getFileName() from the type TUI." Any suggestions on how I should go about the code? I know I haven't supplied a ton of information but I'm not completely sure what information is pertinent.

Comment: You need an instance of TUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your method `getFileName()` is not static, so it belongs to an object and you're trying to access it though the class and not an object. If it's the same fileName for every TUI object you just need to make the field `fileName` and the method `getFileName()` static.

```
public static void getFileName() {
```

If not you have to call the method on an object with the dot operator

```
TUI tui= new TUI();
TUI.getFileName();
```